# How can I authenticate a user with in AWS Cognito with google oauth2 access token in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-identity

I am trying to figure out how I can add Google Authentication (Google Identity Services) to my web app currently using AWS Cognito. My frontend is in Vue and backend in .NET.

What I got so far is in Vue:

1. Button so the user can sign in, which gives me an Auth Code
2. Post the code to my API for authentication

In my .NET API

1. get a token from the code using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(...)
2. parsing the token to get the user details
3. ... sign in the user to my Cognito User Pool if a user with this email exists or create new account if user does not exist

I cannot find any examples how to do this. Any ideas or should I rethink something here?

I tried different calls using AdminInitiateAuthRequest, but not sure this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the AWS Offical Code Lib Doc under the ***Code examples for Amazon Cognito Identity Provider using AWS SDKs*** section.

This example (the closest one to your use case) shows these tasks as part of the .NET Example:

- Sign up a user with a user name, password, and email address.
- Confirm the user from a code sent in email.
- Set up multi-factor authentication by associating an MFA application
  with the user.
- Sign in by using a password and an MFA code.

[Sign up a user with an Amazon Cognito user pool that requires MFA using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cognito-identity-provider_example_cognito-identity-provider_Scenario_SignUpUserWithMfa_section.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this is using MFA not Google Identity Services to sign in?